# Laravel session timeout warning with socket.io

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a lock screen for user after 20 minutes ( for testing I put 20 seconds).

I created a middleware, which redirects to locked screen where user can insert the password to unlock it again. This works fine on reload, but I would like to do it with socket.io so the user will get a warning let's say 5 minutes before the account goes to locked status and that's where I am struggling.

This is my middleware

```
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (!$this->session->has('lastActivityTime')) {
            $this->session->put('lastActivityTime', time());
        } else if (time() - $this->session->get('lastActivityTime') > $this->getTimeOut()) {
            broadcast(new SessionTimeoutCheck('hello'));
            $this->session->forget('lastActivityTime');
            $this->session->put('locked', true);

            return redirect($this->getRedirectUrl())->with([$this->getSessionLabel() => 'You have been inactive.']);

        }
        $this->session->put('lastActivityTime', time());

        return $next($request);
    }
```

This works fine with reload.

I have this on my client JS

```
    /**
 * @desc Session timeout warning and lock screen
 */
socket.emit('private.user.channel', {
    channel: 'private.user.channel.' + user_id,
}).on("App\\Events\\API\\SessionTimeoutCheck", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

So now I am wondering if I should create a command, that runs every minute to check if specific time has passed and then show the warning or what would be the best approach?

Comment: I am assuming it gets "locked" once there is inactivity. You can keep a timer in client JS, once it reaches 20 minutes, you can emit it using socket.io to server, or use ajax call to notify client has reached 20 minutes.

Comment: @adis how can I emit this with socket?